# Small program to download wikipedia articles to pdf

Tags: python, pdf, wikipedia

I made a small app to download wikipedia articles (and optionally those that it links to) as PDFs to take on the go.  I'd eventually like to do a text-to-speech option and save the article as an mp3, though that's the next step.  Any thoughts would be helpful.

```
import wikipedia
import pdfkit
import os
from gtts import gTTS

class Page:

    def __init__(self):
        """Set default pdfkit options"""
        self.pdfOptions = {
            'page-size': 'Letter',
            'margin-top': '0.75in',
            'margin-right': '0.75in',
            'margin-bottom': '0.75in',
            'margin-left': '0.75in',
            'javascript-delay' : 2000,
            'minimum-font-size': 512
        }

        self.targetDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
        self.includeLinks = False

    def getArticle(self, articleTitle):
        """fetch the article from wiki by title"""
        self.page = wikipedia.page(articleTitle)
        try:
            self.page.summary
        except wikipedia.exceptions.DisambiguationError as e:
            print "Multiple articles with that name: " + e.options

    def setURL(self,URL):
        """fetch the article by URL"""
        pass

    def download(self):
        """download the article (and maybe the articles it links to"""
        if self.includeLinks == False:
            filename = self.targetDir+"/"+self.page.title+'.pdf'
            pdfkit.from_url(self.page.url, filename, options = self.pdfOptions)
        else:
            for link in self.page.links:
                linkedPage = wikipedia.page(link)
                print "Downloading " + linkedPage.url
                filename = self.targetDir+"/"+linkedPage.title+'.pdf'
                pdfkit.from_url(linkedPage.url, filename, options=self.pdfOptions)

    def speak(self):
        pass
```

Comment: Here's the biggest change that I'd make: _Don't use classes when you don't need to_

Comment: @Dex'ter yeah, I feel it was a bit of a kludge, but I like the feel many python libraries have that are oop.  I'll think about re-designing the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some stylistic and code style points:

- fix the variable naming - in Python, there is a `lower_case_with_underscores` variable naming style ([PEP8 reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions))
- organize your imports as per [PEP8 guidelines](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports) - first, the system-level imports, then third-parties, then your "local" imports. Also, remove unused `from gtts import gTTS` import:

  ```
  import os

  import pdfkit
  import wikipedia
  ```
- [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings) should start with a capital letter and end with a dot
- I think you should define `pdfOptions` as a module-level (or configuration-layer-level) *constant* instead of having them defined as an instance variable
- `if self.includeLinks == False:` can be simplified to `if not self.includeLinks:`
- you should have spaces around the operators inside expressions ([reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements))
- I think you can handle both cases in your `download()` method in a unified way:

  ```
  def download(self):
      links = self.page.links if self.includeLinks else [self.page]
      for link in links:
          page = wikipedia.page(link)
          print("Downloading " + page.url)
          filename = self.targetDir + "/" + page.title + '.pdf'
          pdfkit.from_url(page.url, filename, options=self.pdfOptions)
  ```
- I would also use [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) instead of string-concatenating filename paths